# Saving postgresql array datatype in cakephp ignores all array datatype fields

Tags: postgresql, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Saving model data fails to insert any of array datatype fields. Data array to store.

```
array(
    'catalog_id' => '14',
    'foreign_model[1]' => 'Catalog',
    'foreign_model_key[1]' => (int) 3,
    'foreign_key[1]' => '4',
    'name' => 'T580.26',
    'integer[1]' => '44000',
    'integer[2]' => '3'
    'amount[1]' => '140000';
)
```

Stored are only `catalog_id` and `name` values.

What I have tried so far.

```
$this->Catalog->save($data, array_keys($data));
```

and

```
$this->Catalog->whitelist = array_keys($data);
$this->Catalog->save($data);
```

Any ideas what else can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Array is a data type that is not supported by CakePHP's ORM.

See https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Postgres.php#L53

You can extend the Postgres datasource and add it.

Comment: It seems quite heavy load to carry, as postgresql implements array of everything.

Comment: I've had now several projects with Postgres a large 550+ table medical app and one from the financial world with 170+ tables, both work fine with the limits of the CakePHP ORM. Why do you have to store an array? If it's an array it should be a very likely another table anyway. As I wrote before, the only solution is to extend the Postgres datasource, but this should not take more than a few hours.

Comment: I use arrays for storing EAV records.